# Memory and time efficient PI algorithm (binary)

Tags: c, binary, arduino, digits, pi

just a very simple question. I would like to efficiently and SEQUENTIALLY compute binary digits of pi on an Arduino microprocessor. There is no actual computing purpose in this project, it is for an artistic installation for a friend, with a light pulsing the digits of pi as they are generated.
Therefore I'd need an algorithm sequentially generating binary digits of PI with the following requirements:
- Low memory requirement
- Speed is not really important since the pulsing light frequency will be of the order of a second
- Good asymptotic time complexity, on exampl the BBP algorithm grows linearly in time with the digits computed and it soon gets to be slow on an Arduino board, and I can compute the previous digits since I want to show them.

Any ideas? Thank you very much indeed!

Matteo

Comment: The best way limited to your non-professional purpose is to generate first 20 digits and then generate the others randomly ;-) I'm serious.

Comment: Or compute the first few thousand bits on a PC and copy them to the Arduino.

Comment: PI is an irrational number so the internal representation would be a float or a double.  When you talk about bits, I assume you know which particular floating point representation of the number you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

Well you may easily find billions of binary digits of pi online, just copy them, put into a file, and ......

I really think it's the best way to solve your problem.